# Delete a folding block in Visual Studio

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

When I want to delete a block, I used to fold it first, and then pressed `cmd`+`del`, but it only deleted the first line rather than the whole folding block.

How to do this just the same as I press `cmd`+`del` or `cmd`+`x` in Jetbrains Webstorm ?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to accomplish this in Webstorm or Visual Studio?  Your tags and title do not match the contents of your question.  Edit your question to clarify your question, do not, reply to this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your selection of the code to be deleted needs to include the closing bracket / brace.

[image: before deletion]

This is the result of deletion

[image: after deletion]